# I can't access one of two subcollections in firestore data base. React

Tags: reactjs, database, google-cloud-firestore

I have two subcollections inside the same document[image: you can see in the picture]

I am able to access the first one with this code:

```
useEffect(() => {
const getData = () => {                                       // get data from firestore to app
 
  const q = query(collection(db, `lists/my lists/${currentList}`), orderBy('queryPreference'));

  onSnapshot(q, (snapshot) => {
    firestoreList = [];                                       // reset firestoreList after every change to avoid copies in items array
    firestoreIds = [];
    snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
      console.log('subcol item', doc)
      firestoreList.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id });
      firestoreIds.every(id => id !== doc.id) && firestoreIds.push(doc.id);
      
    });
    if (firestoreList.length === 0) {
      setItems(items.concat(newItem));
    } else {
      setItemIds(firestoreIds);
      setItems(firestoreList);
    }
  }); 
}

getData();
console.log('get data test')
}, [currentList]);
```

where `currentList` is hard coded to 'shopping list'. If i change `currentList` to 'to do list' firebase doesn't return anything (no errors either). Both names and ids of of both collections are spelled as above: 'shopping list' and 'to do list'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be like this:

```
const q = query(collection(db, 'lists', 'my lists', currentList), 
orderBy('queryPreference'));
```

Comment: same, works with 'shopping list', doesn't work with  'to do list'.

Comment: are there any documents inside the to do list? Is there a 'queryPreference' field?
From the docs :  _An orderBy() clause also filters for existence of the given fields. The result set will not include documents that do not contain the given fields._

Comment: thanks, yep, the documents didn't have `queryPreference` field.